# symbol-plist returns a list for an elisp symbol with value

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
 (symbol-plist 'default-directory)
```

returns

```
(permanent-local t safe-local-variable stringp variable-documentation 341707)
```

How to understand the plist of `default-directory` symbol in elisp? (or) what does the six list elements in symbol plist represent?

Note: default-directory is a symbol with the current elisp script dir as its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **property list** conceptually maps keys to values. The representation is a plain list on the form `(KEY1 VALUE1 KEY2 VAULE2 KEY3 VALUE3 ...)`.

In other words, you should read the property list so that `permanent-local` has the value `t`, `safe-local-variable` has the value `stringp` and `variable-documentation` the value `341707`.

You can use `plist-get` to get a value of a key. Unfortunately, with this function you can't tell apart a property with the value `nil` and the case where the key is missing. Fortunately, you can use `plist-member` for this, it returns the rest of the list starting with the key, or `nil` if the key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

See [Standard Symbol Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Properties.html#Standard-Properties) in the manual.
Any others any package can randomly add with `put`.